# \Python\Python36\lib\os.py", line 669, in __getitem__ raise KeyError(key) from None, KeyError: 'DB_HOST'

Tags: python, python-3.6

[I was able to connect through cmd prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/khd4u.png)

```
class Connection:
    def _get_conn(self):
        db_host = os.environ['DB_HOST']
        db_user = os.environ['DB_USER']
        db_passwd = os.environ['DB_PASSWD']
        db_name = os.environ['DB_NAME']
        db_port = os.environ.get('DB_PORT', '3306')
```

But while trying to connect through pycharm, I am getting error in db host.

**The error** :

```
\Python\Python36\lib\os.py", line 669, in __getitem__ raise KeyError(key) from None, KeyError: 'DB_HOST'
```

Comment: Care to share what that error is? Preferably with what you've tried/researched to solve that problem yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The error is pretty clear – You don't have the `DB_HOST` environment variable set.

You'll need to set those environment variables first. Using the values in your screenshot,

```
set DB_HOST=localhost
set DB_USER=root
set DB_PASSWD=Sam2211_
set DB_NAME=test
```

before running the Python script should do.